# My geo location doesn't type on the top of the marker

Tags: android, eclipse, location

Whenever I want to type a location name above the marker, it doesn't

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=37.423156,-122,084917(Label+Name)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

As in this picture http://oi58.tinypic.com/2dgq6a0.jpg

What is the code where I write the text over the marker?

Comment: I cannot see the picture

Comment: The link you mean? I am not allowed to add pictures right now so there is a link for it.

Comment: Yes, but that link is not working

Comment: Try this http://s29.postimg.org/6ut73nmyv/Untitled_3.png

Comment: Your longitude and latitude values are wrong. You should use a point, not a comma to separate decimal values. Like this: q=37.423156,-122.084917

Comment: It didn't work, I copied/pasted what you added and its the sane thing, I even removed the geo:0,0? but it gave me an error, I just want the name above the red marker